# jQuery Show and Hide in C# - postback issue

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I am completely new to C# and I am trying to use jQuery in C# but I am having issues with a postback. More specifically, I have a webform that I divided into two sections "form-part-1" and "form-part-2".

I have a continue link in the middle of the form. This link should (onClick event) hide the "form-part-1" and show "form-part-2".

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#continue").click(function (event) {
    $('#form-part-1').hide();
    $('#form-part-2').show();
   });
  });
</script>
```

I am experiencing issues with the postback as the form sections get hidden/shown for a split second before the postback kicks in. I have done a fair share of reading and tried multiple things but I can't get the jQuery function to work correctly.

I tried to register the script on page load but not success.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){

ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), ....);                    
}
</script>
```

Any tips and suggestions how to get this working would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: So when you click another button / link, the form submits. When that is happening both sections show / hide? Or is it when it returns from the server?

Comment: Could you provide a little more context around the issue?  The structure of your HTML maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it has no transactional effect, you just want to toggle visibility then i suggest you to have only hyperlink not `asp:hyperlink`. it will not even postback your page and you dont need to register any script.

Comment: Thank you all guys for your input. Rashmin's suggestion resolved my issue. Thanks again, it's much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is NOT related to post-back!! First of all check your imported .js extention files well. What i mean is put your jquery import link top of your head tag. Most probably you have compilement time error. Try this way and see it works..

```
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="your_jquery_url.js"></script><!--First-->
   <script type="text/javascript" src="your_functions_url.js"></script><!--Second-->
</head>
```